# Generate an Email when users filed out the form in SharePoint online list using flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, community-site, flow

I have a SharePoint List which has list items that are filled by users. IT department would like to get daily email to when users filled out the form. I have no idea why, when users missed to filled out one or more field, it doesn't send email

Attached:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screen capture of the workflow? Does the workflow depend in the item being checked in?

Answer (score 0):

If they want a daily email, why not just set up an alert? It's easier than a custom flow, and there would be fewer maintenance issues over time.

Comment: What does that mean ? Can you clarify Mike2500?

Comment: Alerts are OOB functionality for any list or library. Navigate to the list/library, and look at the options in the command bar or ribbon. Alerts can be configured to send a daily roll-up of all activity that occurred on the list, or you can specify different frequencies/options/etc.  It's super easy to configure, but you won't get a lot of options for what's actually included in the email. So test it out. If it works for you, then you have an incredibly simple solution. If you need a custom email, then keep going with the workflow route.